# bibliography in standard font

Tags: biblatex

I would like to have the citation and the bibliography in a sans-serif font.

I managed to change the citation to a sans-serif font with `\addtokomafont{footnote}{\footnotesize\sffamily}`.

However, I was not able to change the bibliography to a sans-serif font aswell. How can I do that?

```
   \RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{darwin,
  author    = {Charles Darwin},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  title     = {The Correspondence of Charles Darwin, 1821--1836},
  year      = {1985},
}
@electronic{wade,
  title   = {Darwin, Ahead of His Time, Is Still Influential},
  author  = {Nicholas Wade},
  date    = {2009-02-09},
  url     = {https://www.nytimes.com/2009/02/10/science/10evolution.html},
  urldate = {2018-10-08},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}


  \addtokomafont{footnote}{\footnotesize\sffamily}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite  \autocite{darwin}  \autocite{wade}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a short compilable tex code you have so far to your question ...

Comment: Please note that the usual LaTeX standard font is Computer Modern (or Latin Modern) and does have serifs. I would also not change the font for citations or the bibliography, that will only look weird.

Comment: I added a MWE. However, it doesn't seem to work, as it doesn't recognize \addtokomafont, which I don't understand and I'm not able to resolve as it works on my document...

Comment: `\addtokomafont` will only work with a KOMA class (`scrartcl` instead of `article`) or `scrextend`. Please make sure that the MWE you show here actually resembles the relevant important bits of your real document. Please also explain in more detail what output you would like to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default citations and bibliography are in the document font. In this example that even happens to be the standard LaTeX font.

I strongly recommend not changing citations and bibliography to a different font than the rest of your document. That just looks odd.

You can change the font of the bibliography by redefining `\bibfont`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\addtokomafont{footnote}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\normalsize\sffamily}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{darwin,
  author    = {Charles Darwin},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  title     = {The Correspondence of Charles Darwin, 1821--1836},
  year      = {1985},
}
@electronic{wade,
  title   = {Darwin, Ahead of His Time, Is Still Influential},
  author  = {Nicholas Wade},
  date    = {2009-02-09},
  url     = {https://www.nytimes.com/2009/02/10/science/10evolution.html},
  urldate = {2018-10-08},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite  \autocite{darwin}  \autocite{wade}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography in sans serif font.]